# Mouse jumps to input-bar text when using Google Chrome in Lion

Tags: mouse, google-chrome

I'm using Lion 10.7 and Chrome 13.0.782.

When I'm in Google Chrome and hit “Cmd-T” (new tab) or “Cmd-L” (change location) and any character, my mouse cursor jumps/changes its position to the Chrome input bar.

This is unwanted behaviour. Why is it happening, and how can one disable it?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by disabling my chrome extensions and seeing if the problem is related to one of them. The standard behavior of Chrome is to place the cursor into the input bar so you can type a search or url.
You can see which extensions you have by going to "Window" -> "Extensions" or else by typing `chrome://extensions/` into the input bar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I set up Chrome on Snow Leopard and Lion with identical extensions, but the aberrant behaviour only occurs on Lion – leading me to believe that's where the problem lies.